# Netbeans Team License Header

Tags: netbeans

In a team environment, is there a way to enforce a license header to be inserted for every new Java file in Netbeans Maven project?
I checked this link: 
http://forums.netbeans.org/viewtopic.php?p=95280#95280

However the way I need to configure my own templates does not seem to be synchronized to other people's workspace.
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

until it's reworked on the general netbeans level, maven support cannot do much there.

AFAIK your only option there is to come up with a netbeans module that defines the license and have everyone install that module. But still suboptimal.