# How to set project license header in a NetBeans Module?

Tags: netbeans

Using NetBeans 8.1, how can I set a project license header for a NetBeans module? Specifically, I would like every new Java file I create to be populated with my license header.

I know how to achieve this for a regular NetBeans Java project. I specify the text I would like under the `License Headers` section of the project properties.

[image: NetBeans Java Project Properties]

However, when I try to set the license header of a NetBeans Module project, there is no `License Headers` section in the module's project properties.
[image: NetBeans Module Project Properties]

I would like to set this license at a project level as opposed to at a NetBeans level, because I would like my whole team to get the new template for any files they create. (I know I can change this for the NetBeans overall by going to `Tools -> Template Manager` and customizing it there. However, then my other team members won't get the header.)

I saw a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4704636/netbeans-team-license-header), but this was for a Maven project instead of a NetBeans module project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you can manually set a custom license file for your module project by adding this property to nbproject/project.properties.

```
project.licensePath=./nbproject/licenseheader.txt
```

Then create the new license template and save it to nbproject/licenseheader.txt.

Unfortunately, this seems to be broken in NetBeans 8.1. When I create new files, I get this error message instead of the custom license text: "Error reading included file Templates/Classes/C:\some\path\module1\Templates\Classes\licenseheader.txt"

Using one of the built-in license templates does work. To use the MIT license for example, add this property instead to nbproject/project.properties.

```
project.license=mit
```

Comment: I submitted a bug: https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=267228

Comment: I have tested this and this is the correct answer. Unfortunately, the bug prevents the feature from being used currently. Thank you for logging that bug report - I will have to keep an eye on it.

Answer (score 4):

Solution for NetBeans 8.2. (Likely works in 8.1, as 8.2 produces the error message described by OP.)

1. Create a text file with your license template text:

   <#if licenseFirst??>
   ${licenseFirst}

   ${licensePrefix}Copyright 2017 Whoever you are
   <#if licenseLast??>
   ${licenseLast}

2. Add the template to NetBeans

In the IDE, do Tools->Templates and open the Licenses node. Here you see the list of global license header templates. Press Add... then browse to and select your template file from step 1.

A new entry will appear under Licenses named 'license-XXX.txt' where XXX is your license file name -- all of it, so if you named your file 'license.txt' the new entry will be named 'license-license.txt.txt'.  (Don't panic, you can rename it.)

I called mine FooLicense.
[image]

3. Set the license in your project.
   Add the line

   `project.license=FooLicense`

   to nbproject/project.properties
4. Now when you create a new source, if will include the the specified license header.
5. Bonus! The setting is inherited from the suite project.
   Setting the license in the suite project properties will apply the setting to all modules in the suite.
   Setting the license in module projects overrides the suite license setting.